# JTextField into a separate class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

Question underneath

JtextField, event handling was done within its class.  Modify a new class Question2 so that the button listener is not changed, but the text events are handled by a separate TextHandler class named Q2textHandler.   You can use the ButtonHandler class from the PowerPoint as a guide, but you should make your own TextHandler class and associate it with the JTextField.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

 public class Question4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
    private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 250;

    private JButton cancelButton;
    private JButton okButton;


    public Question4() {

        setTitle("My Button and Frame Handler");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setLocation(FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);

        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );


        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );

        cancelButton = new JButton("CANCEL");
        okButton = new JButton("OK");

        JTextField inputLine = new JTextField();
        inputLine.setColumns(22);
        contentPane.add(inputLine);
        inputLine.addActionListener(this);

        contentPane.add(okButton);
        contentPane.add(cancelButton);

        okButton.addActionListener(this);
        cancelButton.addActionListener(this);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton)
        {
            JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
            String buttonText = clickedButton.getText();
            setTitle("You clicked " + buttonText);
        }
        else 
        {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) event.getSource();
            setTitle("You entered ' " + textField.getText() + "'");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Question4 window = new Question4();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My problem is:

1. I don't know what he's asking. I had a rough idea and thought just make a return statement for setTitle.
2. I don't know if I have to implement ActionListener into the class that I'm making.

Here's what I have so far

```
public class Q2textHandler extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private String text;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    { 
        JTextField textField = (JTextField) event.getSource();
        String text = textField.getText();
        setTitle("You've entered" + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for your `Q2TextHandler` class to extend `JFrame` - only classes that produce their own GUI need to extend `JFrame`. Instead, you should accept a `JFrame` instance in the constructor of your text handler. Store that away and you can call `setTitle` on it at appropriate times.

Comment: ... but on the whole, you are moving in the correct direction. Eventually you will want to assign a new instance of your `Q2TextHandler` class as the action listener for the `JTextField` in the other class. Perhaps try some more edits and update your question with your latest code?

Comment: So am i to remove the else statement because I feel as if what the Exercise is asking me is to remove that.